# Seeing a mismatch in df and du output post deleting a file and nothing in lsof

Tags: linux

df output for `/run` says

```
df -hT /run
Filesystem     Type   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs          tmpfs  9.4G  7.0G  2.4G  76% /run
```

And du says for `/run`

```
sudo du -shc *
915M    total
```

There was a large log file deleted and I ran `sudo lsof -a +L1 /run` and `sudo lsof | grep /run` and did not notice anything with `(deleted)` in it.

A reboot of the machine clears the inconsistency, but would like to know where is this usage coming from. Also the service corresponding to the large log file is stopped and disabled too.

Comment: nice method of finding deleted files still in use! You must be on the right track, even though lsof doesn't list the deleted file. I would still try to restart / reload the service which created the large file in question...

Comment: To Anyone seeing this thread. I was able to fix it by this. lsof and fuser did not help much. I tried restarting the service corresponding to this log and that failed out. Journalctl mentioned there is another file stopping this from starting up, moved that file out and that restarted the service successfully essentially updating the stats in df. Stopped the service and disabled it since i didnt need it.

Comment: go ahead and answer your own question!

Comment: I second @Martin. What you posted might be useful for others.